# How to add a cart functionality in a shopping app?

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I am making a simple shopping app in android. I am using retrofit 2.4 Network Library. I am stuck in 'add to cart' function. Looking for some help...

Code:

```
    homeCall = new ProductCall();
    /* Retrofit Instance */
    homeFit = homeCall.ProductConnect();
    /* Api Instance */
    prodApi = homeFit.create(ProductDetails.class);

    Call<Products> Check = prodApi.getcart("cart",dt.Prod);

    Check.enqueue(new Callback<Products>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Products> call, Response<Products> response) {
            List<Products> list = response.body().getPosts();
            productList.addAll(list);
            Log.d("P_Res", "onResponse: "+productList);
            cartAdapter = new ProductCartAdapter(productList,ProductCart.this);
            recycleCart.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Products> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("CART", "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

`RecyclerAdapter`

```java
public ProductCartAdapter(List<Products> str, Context context) {
    this.prod = str;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ProductCartHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_cart,parent,false);

    return new ProductCartHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductCartHolder holder, int position) {
    Products products = prod.get(position);
    holder.ProdName.setText(products.getProduct_name()+"("+products.getProduct_size()+products.getProduct_sizein()+")");
    holder.ProdPrice.setText("Price: "+products.getProduct_price());

    if (products.getProduct_mrp().equals(products.getProduct_price()))
    {
        holder.ProdDis.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.ProdMrp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        holder.ProdMrp.setText("MRP: "+products.getProduct_mrp());
        holder.ProdDis.setText("" + products.getProduct_discount() + "%");
        holder.ProdMrp.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return prod.size();
}
}
```

Comment: please be specific about your Question.

Comment: @Qasim Whenever I add an item to cart, previous one disappears. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, I can't add products to cart and if I add one product into cart previous ones disappear.
So I found solution of it in two ways -

1) Using a static ArrayList to store all products.

2) Creating a new Cart table in Database where we can store products.

I would prefer using second one as it will be more dynamic solution and using static ArrayList can still give some issues.